# Remove prefix for upload image in Vtiger

Tags: vtiger

When upload image, vtiger add prefix to filename.

```
Befor upload: IMG_NAME.png. 
After upload: 26540_IMG_NAME.png.
```

How I can remove `'26540_'` prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not recommended to change the standard of storing files with the name. Because the prefix (`'26540_' in your case`) is the unique identifier which will add before the filename. And if we upload same file with the same name vTiger treat as a different file.

But still if you dont want to prefix added then customize the code as per below:

1. Open `\data\CRMEntity.php`
2. Search `function uploadAndSaveFile(`
3. Comment the line

   ```
   $upload_status = move_uploaded_file($filetmp_name, $upload_file_path .$current_id . "_" .  $binFile);
   ```
4. Add  (Removed $current_id)

   ```
   $upload_status = move_uploaded_file($filetmp_name, $upload_file_path .  $binFile);
   ```

Save the script and test. Cheers!